# Sed or other script, and regexp solution for cutting a filename

Tags: shell, regex, sed

What I need is to get 2-3 variable from filenames.
I use:

```
FILES=$(ls -tr .../Files/)

for f in $FILES;
    do
......
```

The files look like this:

[letters and/or numbers and (underscore or nothing)][6 digit number][underscore and maximum 6 character or number, or nothing at all][.][extension]

I need the first part [] the six didigt number and the underscore+characters, if it exists. So the 1. [] the 2. [] and the 3.[].

What I tried:

```
echo sanyi_123456_m2.txt | sed -e "s/^\(\w{4,40}\)\_?\(\\d{6}\)\_?\(\\w{,6}\)?\(\.\w{2,4}$\)/\\1 \\2 \\3/g"
```

What I need from it:

```
sanyi_ 123456 _m2
```

Could someone help me with the regexp solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are too many backslashes. Moreover being greedy your first glob will eat up the whole string until the dot. You may want to clear the picture up by using extended regexps. The second underscore is dependent of the last part (according to your description) it must be parenthesized. You don't need the fourth glob (in your version).

Something like this:

```
 echo sanyi_123456_m2.txt | sed -r "s/^([a-z]{4,40})_?([0-9]{6})(_(\w{,6}))?\.\w{2,4}$/\1 \2 \4/g"
```

You may also use perl regexps where non-greedy quantification is possible.

Comment: well I just see, I've removed the underscore separator for you, which was not a task. A bit overthought it ... :)

Comment: Hello
This is almost perfect, I need the underscores if they are present.
But thanks I will save this as well.

Comment: Hello
What it could not handle is: 
filname123123_186597_m6123.csv  format.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect solution was this:

```
$ echo sanyi123456_654321_987654.txt | sed -r "s/^([^_]{4,}_?)([0-9]{6})(_(\w{,6}))?\.\w{2,4}$/\1 \2 \4/g"
```

It is a modified version of the ones the community gave, thanks so much for it.
So far it works with this (all currently) formats:

karfiol_123123.txt

karfiol_123123_mpf123.txt

karfiol123123.txt

karfiol123123_123123.txt

karfiol123123_123123_123123.txt

karfiol123123_123123_mpf123.txt

karfiol123123_mpf123.txt

Thanks again

Comment: This regexp does:
||
^ - line start
||
[^_] - keep _ in results
||
{4,} - min 4 character
||
_? - There is _ or isn't
||
([^_]{4,}_?) - first block, called as \1 
||
[0-9]{6} - exactly 6 digit number
||
([0-9]{6}) - 2nd block, called as \2
||
_ - underscore
||
\w{,6} - maximum 6 number or letter
||
(_(\w{,6}))?- 3rd and 4th block, or nothing(?), called the 4th as \4
||
\.\w{2,4} - one dot (.) and 2-4 digit or letter (extension)
||
$ - end of line

Answer (score 0):

This regexp expression will do the job:

```
echo "hehehehaha_123456_bc34.meh"|sed 's/\([^_]\+_\?\)\([0-9]\{,6\}\)\(_\w\{,6\}\)\?\..*/\1 \2 \3/'
```

Unfortunately, you need to escape almost anything when using sed, hence the ugliness.

Comment: wouldn't it mach on any garbage like ""¬~$ł?%_^" without the 6 numbers (and a structure at all)?

Comment: If no match is found, sed will display the input. Since the "s" command is a search and replace, if no match is found, nothing will be replaced, so the whole input will be given as output. If the file names don't necessarily follow the rules you've given, you need to check the file name before extracting the parts.

Comment: Hello
Thanks it seems to do exactly what I need, I will update, If I find anything.

Comment: @Lacek yes, or we have a -n option (to suppress output) and p flag for the regexp to print. e.g we can do: sed -n 's/....../......./p' to have grep like feature.

Comment: Hello
what it could not handle is:
filename123123_m4564.csv
filename123156.dat
so when there are no underscore before the 2nd part.
But ist much more than I could do alone :) Thanks

Comment: in your original question you said the second underscore is mandatory. You can make it optional by adding \? (or ? in extended regexp) after it.